# How do i make something have like a 20% chance to happen in Python?

Tags: python

The name about sums it up, thanks guys. (Just to make it more specific I'm programming stats and I want to have a certain chance that a stat will raise every time you level up)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use *random* to get a random value between 0 and 1, and compare it to 0,2. Like this:

```
import random
if random.random() < 0.2:
    do_something()
```

Comment: To be more exact use numpy.random.uniform instead of random()